# Missing sub-properties in Live Property Explorer (VS2015)

Tags: visual-studio-2015

The Live Property Explorer is great, but I notice that not all properties appear when expanding some composite properties.  In particular, when examining DataContext, I'm seeing a property of type Matrix3D missing (another value-typed property of Vector3D does show).  The type of the DataContext is correct, but not all properties of that type are shown.

Are there ways to control which sub-properties appear for some property?  Or, how does Live Property Explorer figure out which sub-properties to show vs. not?

I'm not seeing (or, failing to find) documentation online.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it turned out that the missing properties either had no setter or had a private setter.  Making the setters public or providing a dummy setter let me see those properties in Live Property Explorer (not a reasonable solution to change an API for this reason, but workable as a temporary solution for the moment for debugging purposes and for code I control).